# Access 2013 append query to only add new records of date is not already present

Tags: sql, append, ms-access-2013

I have an access 2013 DB I’m creating. Total newbie. I have a tblHistoricalTaxes and a qryTaxes all the fields in tbl match those in qry. The fields are date, total earned, TaxRate and Tax Owed. Tax Owed is just a calculated field. When the qry runs it adds record to tblHistoricalTaxes. I’d like it so every time it runs it does not re-add records if records already exist in tblHistoricalTaxes where a record with that date is already present, Because I only need records in that table from the time they were added. If the tax rate changes in the future, I don’t need a record added for the taxes on that date with the new rate because it’s irrelevant. SQL view says

```
INSERT INTO tblHistoricalTaxes ( [Date], [Total Earned], TaxRate, [Tax Owed])
SELECT qryTotals.Date, qryTotals.[Total Earned], tblInfo.TaxRate, [Total Earned]*[TaxRate] AS [Tax Owed]
FROM tblInfo, qryTotals;
```

What do I need to change? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblHistoricalTaxes ( [Date], [Total Earned], TaxRate, [Tax Owed])
SELECT qryTotals.Date, qryTotals.[Total Earned], tblInfo.TaxRate, [Total Earned]*[TaxRate] AS [Tax Owed]
FROM tblInfo, qryTotals
WHERE qryTotals.Date NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Date] FROM tblHistoricalTaxes )
```